# Spring spel for mocking multiple interfaces

Tags: mocking, mockito, spring-el

I want to create a mock using Mockito to have two interfaces for one mock object in the following way:

```
Mockito.mock(InterfaceA.class, Mockito.withSettings().extraInterfaces(InterfaceB.class));
```

I'm using xml spring config and I want to find a way to declare that mock using SPel.
I've tried the following but without success:

```
<bean id="myMockObject" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="my.package.InterfaceA"/>
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(org.mockito.Mockito).withSettings().extraInterfaces(T(my.package.InterfaceB))}"/>
</bean>
```

Looks like spring can't autowire the mock to the field of type InterfaceB. Could someone suggest where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me; you **do** realize that you have to cast the mock to access the additional interface methods, don't you?

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private Bar barr;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        Bar bar = mock(Bar.class, Mockito.withSettings().extraInterfaces(Baz.class));
        ((Baz) bar).baz();
        ((Baz) this.barr).baz();
    }

    public interface Bar {

        void bar();
    }

    public interface Baz {
        String baz();
    }

}
```

.

```
<bean id="bar" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="foo.Foo$Bar"/>
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(org.mockito.Mockito).withSettings().extraInterfaces(T(foo.Foo$Baz))}"/>
</bean>
```

From the javadocs...

```
 * <p>
 * This mysterious feature should be used very occasionally.
 * The object under test should know exactly its collaborators & dependencies.
 * If you happen to use it often than please make sure you are really producing simple, clean & readable code.

...

 *   //now, the mock implements extra interfaces, so following casting is possible:

...
```

**EDIT**:

I just updated my test and I can inject the bean via the second interface ok...

```
@Autowired
private Baz baz;

@Test
public void foo() {
    when(this.baz.baz()).thenReturn("foo");
    System.out.println(this.baz.baz());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I understood, but I can't figure out why spring can't autowire the bean created in that way to the field of the InterfaceB type. I will edit my question to highlight main problem for me.